# Empty Activity When I try to load JSON from S3

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I navigate to the activity that should load a ListView from a JSON hosted on AWS S3, I get nothing but a blank activity. There's no error message, no errors in the debugger, and Logcat doesn't seem to hold any relevant information.

Here's LoadJSONTask.java:

```
package com.teamplum.projectapple;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.teamplum.projectapple.NewsDO;
import com.teamplum.projectapple.Response;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response> {

    public LoadJSONTask(Listener listener) {

        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface Listener {

        void onLoaded(List<NewsDO> androidList);

        void onError();
    }

    private Listener mListener;

    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            String stringResponse = loadJSON(strings[0]);
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            return gson.fromJson(stringResponse, Response.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {

        if (response != null) {

            mListener.onLoaded(response.getAndroid());

        } else {

            mListener.onError();
        }
    }

    private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            response.append(line);
        }

        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

and here's MainActivity.java:

```
package com.teamplum.projectapple;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

//import com.teamplum.projectapple.NewsDO;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadJSONTask.Listener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView mListView;

    public static final String URL = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tyi-work/Work_Experience.json";

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> mAndroidMapList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String KEY_TIT = "title";
    private static final String KEY_CAT = "category";
    private static final String KEY_DES = "description";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        new LoadJSONTask(this).execute(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(List<NewsDO> androidList) {

        for (NewsDO work : androidList) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

            map.put(KEY_TIT, work.getTitle());
            map.put(KEY_CAT, work.getCategory());
            map.put(KEY_DES, work.getDescription());

            mAndroidMapList.add(map);
        }

        loadListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Toast.makeText(this, mAndroidMapList.get(i).get(KEY_TIT),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void loadListView() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mAndroidMapList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_CAT, KEY_TIT, KEY_DES },
                new int[] { R.id.version,R.id.name, R.id.api });

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I used [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html) tutorial to help make this, if you need any extra information please feel free to ask, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the async task for the URL connection and its working fine.
The problem is either on the parsing or on the activity side. Have you tried putting breakpoints and follow the data?

Comment: I just breakpointed MainActivity.java, and apparently it never runs onLoaded(), onError(), onItemClick or loadListView(), but onCreate() is run, but beyond that, I'm clueless. Do you have any suggestions?